# cant update to php 5.4 ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, php

I am trying to install php 5.4 in ubuntu 12.10 but its not working. I keep getting php5 is already the newest version. (5.3.10).

I tried to add the ondrej/php5-oldstable but still, it wont do the upgrade.

I have done sudo apt-get-update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade.

This is the result of

```
 apt-cache policy php5
```

:

```
php5:
  Installed: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3
  Package pin: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3
  Version table:
     5.4.6-1ubuntu1.7 991
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.6-1ubuntu1 991
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal/main amd64 Packages
     5.3.10-1ubuntu3.10 991
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.3.10-1ubuntu3 991
        500 http://bg.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As you can see I can see the latest php 5.4 in Version Table but cant upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `apt-cache policy php5` clearly shows that the package php5 was pinned to a specific version.

```
php5:
  Installed: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3
  Package pin: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3
```

You have to unpin the package, so that it would be upgradeable.

Run the below command to unpin the `php5` package,

```
sudo apt-mark unhold php5
```

Then try to update that package,

```
sudo apt-get install php5
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. 
I solved the problem. Their was a policy file in /etc/apt/preferences.d that was blocking the update.

Comment: How did you know this?

Comment: Yes, the package pin.I failed to see that in the output of `apt-cache policy php5` command.